# Accessing a link inside fancybox outside of fancybox

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have a page setup that is accessed through a fancybox iframe. How can a link that is inside the fancybox iframe, load in the parent window of the iframe? So if the user clicks the link, it will reload the page and load the clicked link. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `target` attribute of the `<a>`.

Example:

```
<a href="yourLink.html" target="_top">Click me!</a>
```

Target can accept five value types:

- "_top"        - the top document window
- "_parent"     - the parent window (similar to _top)
- "_blank"      - new window/tab
- "_self"       - the same window/iframe
- "*framename*" - the named iframe/frame